# Why does geoip throw an exception?

Tags: php, laravel, geoip

Why this code:

```
geoip_country_code_by_name('unknown');
```

generate ErrorException, when must return false ?

Comment: Do you have GeoIP *installed*? http://www.php.net/manual/en/geoip.setup.php ErrorExceptions come with error messages indicating what the error was, by the way.

Comment: yep, geoip is installed. Error message: "geoip_country_code_by_name(): Host unknown not found", but in documentation (http://php.net/manual/en/function.geoip-country-code-by-name.php) this function should return false for this situation.

Comment: Have you tried a real hostname? Maybe it knows that `unknown` isn't a legit one.

Comment: Why is this question tagged with laravel? It seems unrelated, at least with the information provided in the question.

Comment: Yes, if host or ip not in geoIP database, the same.

Comment: @Fnatte - because this problem i have only in laravel.

Comment: do you execute the code within a framework? It can be that the framework code turns warnings to exceptions

Comment: @Fnatte: Laraval _is to the point_. it defines the error handler which throws the `ErrorException`.

Comment: PHP generates a notice (no ip found for hostname), Laravel makes an `ErrorException` of it.

Comment: @hek2mgl yes, without framework all good.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bug in GeoIP package and is not fixed in any release (<= 1.0.8). It's fixed in the trunk however ([see this revision](http://svn.php.net/viewvc?view=revision&revision=318845)). You can solve this by compiling the source from the latest trunk.

*Edited: thanks to [Wrikken](https://stackoverflow.com/users/358679/wrikken) for pointing out how Laravel handles errors.*

With GeoIP <= 1.0.8 `geoip_country_code_by_name` will trigger an error (*E_NOTICE*) whenever the name cannot be found. Laravel will always set [error_reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to *-1* and handle all errors (even notices) and translate them into *ErrorExceptions*. Normally one can catch ErrorExceptions using a try-catch block, but in this case it is not possible because Laravel never throws the exception, it just translate it for displaying and logging purposes.

It is possible to ignore the error with the [@-operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php). It's a bit bad to do so since it will ignore all errors that the function might throw. In this case however, the only other error `geoip_country_code_by_name` can trigger is warning when the database can't be reached. Therefore you can safely ignore the error if you make sure the database is available: *(Code not tested)*

```
if (geoip_db_avail(GEOIP_COUNTRY_EDITION))
{
    @geoip_country_code_by_name('unknown');
}
else
{
    // Throw exception or handle the error
    throw new Exception(
       "Required database not available at " . 
       geoip_db_filename(GEOIP_COUNTRY_EDITION) 
    );

}
```

**Edit:**
Laravel now throws the ErrorException so that one can catch it using a try-catch block. At the time of writing, this change is not yet in any released tag. But a catching errors will *probably* work with Laravel/Framework >= 4.0.8.

Comment: Sure about what? That the trunk has it fixed? I didn't try but [this](http://svn.php.net/viewvc/pecl/geoip/trunk/geoip.c?r1=318845&r2=318844&pathrev=318845) makes it pretty clear.

Comment: If you edit in the part about Laravel creating Exceptions from Notices, it's complete, and I'll delete my answer :) (as soon as I return, as I'm about to go out...)

Comment: @Wrikken Added the Laravel part. Anything missing?:)

Comment: @Fnatte:, well, `try... catch..`-ing _does_ work, otherwise, perfect :)

Comment: Erm, (1) Laravel _does_ throw the `ErrorException` (2) One _can_ catch it.  Only _if nothing catches it_, the default exception handler is called which is just a generic 'something is wrong' message is `debug'` is set to `false in `app/config/app.php`, or a complete exception + trace is it is set to `true`. So what works for this problem are several options: (1) suppress the error with `@` (2) Use `error_reporting()` to (temporarily?) ignore `E_NOTICE` errors. (3) Recomple `mod_geoip` so it does not triggger notices. (4) Use a `try{ ...} catch {...}` block around the code.

Comment: Wow. Laravel 4 has been throwing ErrorExceptions since... yesterday [(this commit)](https://github.com/laravel/framework/commit/694d624d89ec3a60bc27a5e37fbc9d24b5464502). I didn't have that commit in my test environment. I will edit the answer.

Comment: @Wrikken i tried to use `try{...} catch {...}`, but its not working. Laravel still handled error. So (4) not suitable

Comment: @maxim.u: _my_ Laravel does. What exact version are you running?

Comment: @Wrikken laravel-4.0.7, php-5.5.4. I mean  `try{ geoip_country_code_by_name('unknown')} catch(\ErrorException $e){}catch(\Exception $e){}`  does not catch the error. Default laravel handler does.

Comment: Hm, you're right, it does something different in HTTP context then in CLI context (which is evil), it does not _throw_ the exception (which is even more evil), but directly calls the defined catch function directly. The only way for it to work: alter `$this->handleException($e);` in `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Exception/Handler.php`, line 133, to `throw $e;` (what they should have done in the first place.

Comment: (FWIW: this is already altered in the repo's, but apparently not in a tag yet, so an update with composer doesn't work until they do)

Comment: Correction: an update with composer set to `4.0.*` does not work, an update to `dev-master` _does_.

Answer (score 1):

In 1.1.0 module version bug fixed https://pecl.php.net/package-changelog.php?package=geoip&release=1.1.0